# How to create button like AppCompat AlertDialog Button?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I want to overlay system window.

I'm trying to create button like AppCompat style.

I have tried this:

XML:

```
<LinearLayout 
    ...
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
/>

<!-- 
      My layout  ... 
      And button
      The buttonBarButtonStyle is in Theme.AppCompat and Theme.AppCompat.Light
 -->

 <Button 
      style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Close" />
```

Service:

```
LayoutInflater inflater;

public void setTheme(int theme)
{
    ContextThemeWrapper contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, theme);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this).cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);
}

public void onCreate(){
    boolean themeDark = getThemeDark();
    setTheme(themeDark ? R.style.Theme_AppCompat : R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light);
    super.onCreate();
    createView(); // in this method i'm only inflating view using: inflater.inflate(layoutId, null); and adding view to window
}
```

And it's working in AppCompat but not in AppCompat.Light. I have the button from style AppCompat (dark). Screenshots:

Dark (works):

[image: Dark]

Dark focused (works):

[image: Dark Focused]

Light (works):

[image: Light]

Light focused (not working):

[image: Light focused]

In this image we can see all is ok. However in a phone it looks ugly.

I want to make this button (I have created in this same app with this same theme AlertDialog using android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog) and it's looks ok:

[image: Light focused working]

I don't know why it's not working.
How can I do it? The problem is with button background when focused. I don't know why the background is from dark style.
I was tried to set AlertDialog.AppCompat.Light theme but not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have fixed it.

I replaced `Button` with `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton 
      style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Close" />
```

Now it's working.

Comment: remember that every `Button` made inside a `AppCompatActivity` automatically becomes a `AppCompatButton`

Comment: @NicolasTyler  Yes I know. But in that case I adding view to system window. I'm doing it in service. However problem is solved.